# Android- Method compress must be called from worker thread

Tags: android, bitmap, digital-signature

I am trying to implement an image view which displays the signature I draw in the SignatureActivity class. I am receiving an error on line:

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
```

```
public class SignatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    File file;
    LinearLayout mContent;
    View view;
    signature mSignature;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    // Creating Separate Directory for saving Generated Images
    String DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/UserSignature/";
    String pic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String StoredPath = DIRECTORY + pic_name + ".png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);

        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasLayout);
        mSignature = new signature(getApplicationContext(), null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // Dynamically generating Layout through java code
        mContent.addView(mSignature, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mGetSign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getsign);
        mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        view = mContent;
        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        mClear.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);

        // Method to create Directory, if the Directory doesn't exists
        file = new File(DIRECTORY);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
    }

    Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == mClear) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
                mSignature.clear();
                mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (v == mGetSign) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    isStoragePermissionGranted();
                } else {
                    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Calling the same class
                    recreate();
                }
            } else if(v == mCancel){
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                // Calling the BillDetailsActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignatureActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };


    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public class signature extends View {

        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();

        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }

        public void save(View v, String StoredPath) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            try {
                // Output the file
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(StoredPath);
                v.draw(canvas);

                // Convert the output file to Image such as .png
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignatureActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imagePath", StoredPath);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }

        }

        public void clear() {
            path.reset();
            invalidate();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    lastTouchX = eventX;
                    lastTouchY = eventY;
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                    for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                        float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                        float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                        expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                        path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                    }
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;

                default:
                    debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                    return false;
            }

            invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;

            return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string) {

            Log.v("log_tag", string);

        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
            } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
            } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
            }
        }

        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have created a thread however it still is not working.

```
new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                    }}.start();
```

Fixed this error by changing code for granting permission to device

```
Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == mClear) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
                mSignature.clear();
                mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (v == mGetSign) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    isStoragePermissionGranted();
                } else {
                    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Calling the same class
                    recreate();
                }
            } else if(v == mCancel){
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                // Calling the BillDetailsActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignatureActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you please add the entire logcat error?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `bitmap.compress` method on the main (UI) thread, which can block the main thread and cause your UI to freeze.  To fix this, you should run this code on a background (worker) thread - which you should be doing anyway, because you're also doing file I/O, which can also block the main thread.

There are many ways to do this, using AsyncTask, Executors, Threads, Handlers, etc.  You can find some info in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads).

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking up examples of these and I cannot seem to figure out how to implement a thread and I am getting errors.

Comment: I have added the thread I created to this question. See above

Comment: "getting errors" kind of need the errors to help with that

Comment: Sorry, there is no errors as such this is coming up in run : D/ViewRootImpl@4c82ee3[SignatureActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0 T
D/ViewRootImpl@4c82ee3[SignatureActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
V/log_tag: Panel Saved.When save button is pressed nothing happens to the App.

Comment: It sounds like this solved your problem, and you're having a different problem now.  If so, please mark this as accepted and/or upvote it to help others, and then ask your new problem as a separate question so that you can fully describe it and people can help you more easily.